# How I can add the parameter "All" on a SelectInput in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

and thanks for reading and helping me.

I have a list of grades that has the names of the students and I am making a shiny app with it. I added a SelectInput to choose the students, but I would like to know if it is possible to add a row in the SelectInput with the option "All".

Anyone know how I can add this?
The code for the selectinput is the following:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  selectInput("alumnos", "Selecciona a un alumno:",
              choices = asistencias$Alumno
              )
  
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try using `pickerInput` from `shinyWidgets` package.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
    shinyWidgets::pickerInput("alumnos", "Selecciona a un alumno:",
              choices = unique(mtcars$cyl), multiple = TRUE,
              options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE)
  )
) 
server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]